# About differentiability and partial differentials of function.

Tags: analysis

Problem Statement:
Given:$$f: \mathbb {R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb {R},(x,y)\rightarrow \begin{cases} 0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \\ \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\end{cases} $$
Need to show that it is not differentiable at (0,0), but all directional derivatives exist.

I showed that all directional derivatives exist. Also, I showed that the partial derivatives at (0,0) are 1 and 0,which are continuous on $\mathbb {R^2}$ Doesn't this imply that f is continuously differentiable i.e totally differentiable everywhere? But I am supposed to show it is NOT differentiable.
This is confusing me a lot. If you could point out where my mistake is I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

$f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if $$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\cfrac{f(0+h,0+k)-f(0,0)-h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)-k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0,$$ or in particular (given your calculations and the definition of $f$) if $$0=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\cfrac{\frac{h^3}{h^2+k^2}-0-h-0}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{-hk^2}{(h^2+k^2)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}.$$ Letting $(h,k)\to(0,0)$ along the line $h=k$ shows us that this isn't true.

---

Your mistake is in concluding that the first partials were continuous. Indeed, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=\begin{cases}1 & (x_0,y_0)=(0,0)\\\frac{x^4+3x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & (x_0,y_0)\ne(0,0),\end{cases}$$ which isn't continuous at the origin (try approaching along the $y$-axis).